# Inconsistent printing sequence for flask application

Tags: python

The program is printing errors inconsistently each time a request is made to this url. The last 2 lines of this error trace print some debug info. The print lines include text SCHEMA and JSON. Its all over the place it is not ideal for my way of debugging, how can I ensure a consistent print sequence?

```
[2018-05-12 22:59:09,766] ERROR in app: Exception on /test [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/app.py", line 13, in test
    validation.validate("{'asdf':'testing title'}")
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/model/series/seriesValidator.py", line 21, in validate
    ModelValidator.validate(self, json)
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/validate.py", line 16, in validate
    errors = [e for e in validator.iter_errors(json)]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iter_errors'
JSON:  {'asdf':'testing title'}
SCHEMA:  {'$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/schema#', 'required': ['title'], 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'description': {'type': 'string'}, 'title': {'type': 'string'}}}
127.0.0.1 - - [12/May/2018 22:59:09] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 500 -
J
```

Then I made 2 more requests and it is inconsistent:

```
JSON:  {'asdf':'testing title'}
SCHEMA:  {'$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/schema#', 'required': ['title'], 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'description': {'type': 'string'}, 'title': {'type': 'string'}}}
[2018-05-12 22:59:18,102] ERROR in app: Exception on /test [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/app.py", line 13, in test
    validation.validate("{'asdf':'testing title'}")
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/model/series/seriesValidator.py", line 21, in validate
    ModelValidator.validate(self, json)
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/validate.py", line 16, in validate
    errors = [e for e in validator.iter_errors(json)]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iter_errors'
127.0.0.1 - - [12/May/2018 22:59:18] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 500 -
JSON:  {'asdf':'testing title'}
[2018-05-12 22:59:42,329] ERROR in app: Exception on /test [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
SCHEMA:  {'$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/schema#', 'required': ['title'], 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'description': {'type': 'string'}, 'title': {'type': 'string'}}}
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/app.py", line 13, in test
    validation.validate("{'asdf':'testing title'}")
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/model/series/seriesValidator.py", line 21, in validate
    ModelValidator.validate(self, json)
  File "/Users/matt/PycharmProjects/WebService/validate.py", line 16, in validate
    errors = [e for e in validator.iter_errors(json)]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iter_errors'
127.0.0.1 - - [12/May/2018 22:59:42] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 2):

`print` goes to `stdout`, tracebacks and logging go to `stderr`. The two streams often intermingle like this. If you use proper logging then it will all be on `stderr` and all will be well.

At the top of your file, do:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Then instead of printing, do:

```
log.info('JSON: %s', json_data)
```

You may also have to configure logging to see the output in the console.